# Camel: CamelFailureEndpoint not set when sending exchange to DeadLetterChannel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm developing a project which involves Camel (version 2.15.3) dealing with files.
I have some folders where messages come under the form of files that must be consumed, sent to a bean that performs some actions and then moved to the proper output folder.

In my `camel-context.xml` file I assumed that the `deadLetterErrorHandler` will be the strategy to deal with exceptions:

```
<bean id="deadLetterErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder" >
        <property name="deadLetterUri" value="${deadLetterUri}"/>
</bean>
```

where `deadLetterUri` resolves to a folder as well.

I also configured a route like this:

```
<route id="lpcMillenniumRoute">
        <from uri="lpcMillenniumInputFolder"/>
        <to uri="log:testLog" />
        <to uri="bean:fileManagerService?method=manageXmlFile(${body.absoluteFilePath})"></to>
        <to uri="lpcMillenniumOutputFolder"/>
</route>
```

The error route is configured as follows:

```
<route id="errorRoute">
            <from ref="deadLetterUri" />
            <log message="header.CamelFailureEndpoint = ${header.CamelFailureEndpoint}" loggingLevel="ERROR" />
            <choice>             
                <when>
                    <simple>${header.CamelFailureEndpoint} == 'lpcMillenniumRoute'</simple>
                    <log message="Writing ${in.header[camelFileName]} to ${properties:lpcMillenniumErrorFolderUri}" loggingLevel="ERROR" />
                    <to uri="lpcMillenniumErrorFolder"/>
                </when>
                .....
```

The problem is that as soon as the bean throws an exception I would have expected the `header.CamelFailureEndpoint` variable to be gracefully set to the value of which endpoint failed, as reported in the [Camel dead letter channel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html).

This kind of information is useful to me in order to correctly dispatch the message to the proper error folder.

Unfortunately the log I set always returns nothing.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that your `deadLetterErrorHandler` saves the message on the filesystem. Then afterwards its picked up by the `errorRoute` from the filesystem. This is a different exchange, so the failure and exception headers from the exchange that caused the error not available.

You can try to join the `lpcMillenniumRoute` and the `errorRoute` in the same camelcontext (if not already), and set up the `deadLetterUri` with `direct:dlc` and the Errorroute with `<from uri="direct:dlc"/>`. Then the `errorRoute` processes the same exchange that caused the error, and the camel failure and exception headers will be available.

Comment: It worked as you suggested. Moreover I also tried with the `seda:dlc` and worked the same. Thanks.